# Strange: Entity framework (code first) slower and behave strangly with generic repository

Tags: performance, generics, load, ef-code-first, repository

We have a generic repository done with code-first technique. As the code is in testing we realized that the generic repository is relatively slower than that of directly accessing the DBContext and loading data. In order to simulate the issue for you all, we simplify the generic repository wrote a new code and that code is pasted below..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using DemoTest.Bll.Models;
using DemoTest.Bll.DB;
using MasIt.Common.BackEnd;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace DemoTest.Bll.Handlers
{
    public abstract class MyHandlerBase<E, T>
        where E : DbSet<T>
        where T : class, IBaseObject
    {
        public MyHandlerBase(E mySet)
        {
            dbSet = mySet;
        }
        public E dbSet;
        protected IEnumerable<T> GetAllNew(Func<T, bool> predicate)
        {
            try
            {
                return dbSet.Where(predicate).AsEnumerable();
            }
            catch { return null;  }
        }

    }

public class StudentHandler : MyHandlerBase<DbSet<Student>, Student>
{
    public StudentHandler()
        :base(DemoDBContext.GetContext().Students)
    {
        //_entitySet = new DemoDBContext().Students;
    }

    public List<Student> getList(bool option1)
    {
        if (option1)
        {
            // Option 1 this is very fast and hit the Student Constructor only once
            IEnumerable<Student> response1 = this.dbSet.Where(x => x.StudentId == 10).AsEnumerable();
            return response1.ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            // Option 2 this is very slow and hit the Student Constructor the student record count of the table
            IEnumerable<Student> response2 = this.GetAllNew(x => x.StudentId == 10);
            return response2.ToList();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Can anybody say why Option 2 is slower.. it is not just slow, it hits the Student class constructor many times, while option 1 hits the constructor only once.. So it seems to us that option 1 load only the matching record, where as option 2 load all the records and match them in memory to filter records..

Generic Repository is a must.. Any fix is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

Got the fix...

Replacing 
"Func<T, bool> predicate" with 
"Expression<Func<E, Boolean>>" predicate did the trick..

Man .. a horrible nightmare is just over..